# Need to extract a josn value for nested requests in JMeter using Jsonpath extractor

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

I have response which derived from a action. I need to extract a value of **userid** node using json path extractor in JMeter

{
"ABC": "{"response":{"userId":user1,"caseId":0,"name":"Json","email":"json@xyz.com","mobileNumber":"1223456789","countryCodeId":"1","countryCode":"+90","emailOTP":830782,"mobileOTP":301879,"mobileOTPString":null,"otpCreationDate":"2021-10-14T10:01:38.5802765Z","configOTPTimeOut":120,"redirectUrl":null,"isOTPExpired":false,"countryCodeValidMessage":null,"mobileNumberValidMessage":null,"offset":"00:00:00","postStatus":false,"postMessage":null,"id":null,"response":null,"isProceedToCreateMeeting":false},"successcode":0,"message":null}"
}

I have tried $..ABC.response.userId, it says NoMatch. what is the correct syntax to extract userId node which is present inside response

Comment: Check why your response is not returning a valid json. Try parsing `JSON.parse(json)` it. `$.ABC.response.userId` is the right jsonpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're showing us is not a valid JSON (you can check it yourself using i.e. https://jsonlint.com/ website or equivalent) therefore you won't be able use either [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/)

Unless it's a copy-paste issue you're limited to [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), example regular expression would be something like:

```
"userId"\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*,
```

[image]